# Can't resolve Font Awesome modules in React Native

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

I am trying to get Font Awesome icons running my React Native application by following the [instructions posted here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/react). However, after completing the instructions, my simulator doesn't load the application and the command line gives me the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` from file `/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/App.js`, the package `/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

  * `/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/index.js(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
  * `/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/index.js/index(.native||.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json)`
    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:92:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:237:485)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:116:25)
    at dependencies.map.result (/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:298:29)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:294:16)
    at /Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:159:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:239:307)
    at /Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:239:467
 BUNDLE  [ios, dev] ../../index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░ 0.0% (0/1), failed.
```

My code is as follows:

`App.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import MainApp from './src/components/MainApp';
import AudioExample from './src/components/AudioExample';

// For icons we use font awesome
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faStroopwafel } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faStroopwafel)

AppRegistry.registerComponent('audioApp', () => MainApp);

export default MainApp;
```

Relevant piece of `LangPage.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Picker} from 'react-native'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Menu from './Menu'

class LangPage extends React.Component{
    static propTypes = {
        List: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        passFunc: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.boxContainers}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="stroopwafel" />
                    <Text style={styles.header}>Select a Language</Text>
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.boxContainers, styles.menuBox]}>
                    <Menu givenL={this.props.List} selectFunc={this.props.passFunc}/>
                </View>
            </View>
            )
    }
}
```

For reference, I am using:

```
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0-14",
"@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0-11",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.1.0-11",
"i": "^0.3.6",
"npm": "^6.3.0",
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0"
```

Any thoughts on how I could fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Good morning,

I strongly recommend you to use the `react-native-vectors-icons` library instead of directly using fontAwesome. It may be why it doesn't work. For more informations, click [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons).

**EDIT**: You need to import the react-native-vector-icons in your dependencies. Go in your `package.json` file and type this line in the 'dependencies' section :

```
"react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",
```

In your `LangPage.js` file, you will be able to import them like this :

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

With that done, you will be able to display easily icons from font-awesome in your react native components, just like that :

```
<Icon
   color={Colors.primaryBackground}
   name={stroopwafel}
   size={40}
/>
```

Hope it helped :)

Have a good day

Comment: I tried this, removing the relevant lines from my `App.js` and adding the lines you suggest, but now I get the error: `error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome` from `/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/src/components/LangPage.js`: Module `react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome` does not exist in the Haste module map`

Comment: Did you add the dependency in your package.json file?

Comment: yes it is in there. `"react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",`

Comment: Did you typed **yarn/npm install** in your terminal after adding it to your dependencies? Maybe it isn't yet in your project.

Comment: It is bizarre. I am doing that. Do I have to add anything to my `App.js` file?

Comment: Normally, with the steps I gave you, you should be able to use these vector images. I don't know what's happening for real.

Answer (score 1):

William is on the right track for getting you where you want to be, however, there are a couple of things missing from his answer.

react-native-vector-icons needs to be linked, either by running

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

or by following the [manual linking example](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) in the README.

You can check if linking has worked correctly by checking the following files;

Android:

```
android/app/src/main/java/.../MainApplication.java
android/settings.gradle
android/app/build.gradle
```

iOS:

```
ios/<APP_NAME>/Info.plist
ios/<APP_NAME>/<APP_NAME>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

I may have missed some files, but these should be the main ones.

If you have used `react-native-create-app` and have an expo project that hasn't been ejected yet, then I would recommend using the expo [vector-icons](https://github.com/expo/vector-icons) package.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The FontAwesome packages are indeed in the iOS files. I linked using the command you gave as well as `react-native link` and I still get an error that says `error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome` from `/Users/agaidis/Auto-ID-Lab/AudioApp/src/components/LangPage.js`: Module `react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome` does not exist in the Haste module map`

Comment: If you open your project in Xcode do you see links to all of the fonts in the side panel under `Resources`? Also, when you select a font in the resources tab you should have your application selected under the `Target Membership`. If you then select the root folder in the Xcode tab and select your `Target` and then `Build Phases` tab, you should be able to see `libRNVectorIcons.a` under the `Link Binary With Libraries` tab and a list of all the fonts from resources in the `Copy Bundle Resources` tab.

Answer (score 0):

just:

> npm i --save @fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome

Answer (score 0):

remove the libraries

> "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
>
> "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.5.0",

and then Reload (`cmd+R`) the app